# Estimate asymptotics of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Consider the following ODE eigenproblem of $y(x)$
\begin{equation}
    y''  + \left[\varepsilon + b^2 x - \left(a + \frac{b^2}{2}x^2 \right)^2 \right] y=0
\end{equation}
with eigenvalue $\varepsilon$, real constants $a,b$. The boundary condition is $y(\pm\infty)=0$. Numerically, this turns out to have well-behaved eigensolutions.

My question is how to see the typical length scale of the eigensolution $y(x)$, i.e., how it asymptotically decays. For instance, if $y(x)\sim e^{-x^2/c^2}$, $c$ is the length scale I mean.

---

This ODE can also be shown to have the following general solution
\begin{equation}
    y(x)= \sum_{s=\pm} C_s\, e^{-arx_s - \frac{x_s^3}{2}} \mathscr{H}_\mathrm{T}(\alpha,\beta_s,\gamma,x_s)
\end{equation}
with integration constants $C_\pm$, $r=(\frac{3}{b^2})^{\frac{1}{3}}$,  $\alpha=r^2\varepsilon,\beta_\pm=\pm3,\gamma=2ra,x_\pm=\pm x/r$ and $\mathscr{H}_\mathrm{T}$ the [triconfluent Heun's function](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=HeunT). However, its asymptotics is **not** solely determined by the exponential factor, because $\mathscr{H}_\mathrm{T}$ is not truncated to be a finite polynomial for these $\beta$'s and actually diverges beyond the exponential suppression, although overall $y(x)$ decays well. So it's not clear to me whether this general form helps the above question.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti What you suggest gives nothing but the leading cubic exponential factor in the general solution I provided. But as I mentioned there, it is not enough to determine the asymptotics. And I checked numerically, it indeed doesn't seem to scale as $e^{-c x^3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $b \neq 0$. Write the equation in the form
$$
\frac{{\mathrm{d}^2 y(x)}}{{\mathrm{d}x^2 }} = \left( {\frac{{b^4 }}{4}x^4  + ab^2 x^2  - b^2 x + a^2  - \varepsilon } \right)y(x).
$$
Take
$$
f(x) = \frac{{b^4 }}{4}x^4  + ab^2 x^2  - b^2 x,\quad g(x) = a^2  - \varepsilon 
$$
and choose an interval $(x_*,+\infty)$ on which $f$ is positive. Applying the results of [$\S2.7(\text{iii})$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.7.iii) of the DLMF with $a_1=x_*$ and $a_2=+\infty$, it is seen that there is a unique solution such that
$$
y(x) = \left( \frac{{b^4 }}{4}x^4  + ab^2 x^2  - b^2 x \right)^{ - 1/4} \exp \left( { - \int_{x_*}^x {\sqrt {\frac{b^4}{4}t^4  + ab^2t^2  - b^2 t} \,\mathrm{d}t} } \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $x\to +\infty$. After some binomial expansions and elimination of unnecessary constant factors, we can see that there is a unique solution such that
$$
y(x) = \exp \left( { - \frac{b^2}{6}x^3  - ax} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $x\to +\infty$. You can do a similar analysis for an interval of the form $(-\infty,x_{**})$ on which $f$ is positive.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I missed something basic. The exponential factor you gave is exactly the $s=+$ one in my general solution. Using the general solution form with the boundary condition, I did numerically obtain quickly decayed solutions $y(x)$ as a whole. However, as I mentioned, the H_T does not truncate and diverges well beyond the exponential suppression, i.e., each of $s=\pm$ part in the solution diverges at both $x=\pm\infty$ (numerically I can also see this). Only the sum gives the finite result. This seems different from the cubic exponential asymptotics. Or I misunderstood?

Comment: In other words, if I substitute $y(x)=\exp \left( { - \frac{b^2}{6}x^3  - ax} \right)v(x)$, the equation for $v(x)$ by all means diverges faster than the $\exp[- x^3b^2/6]$. It is an exact result from the polynomial truncation condition of H_T (in the link in my question). I somewhat feel this suggests something else than the simple asymptotics. But I'm not familiar with this field and probably being stupid. So do you find any contradiction between the asymptotics and what I described?

Comment: You get a second order ODE for $v(x)$. What about another solution, a recessive one at $+\infty$?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Usually only one H_T is defined like in the link in my question. And softwares like Mathematica/Maple implements only one, which I use to confirm what I described.

Comment: I eventually think your solution is nice. In this Sturm-Liouville problem with a discrete spectrum $\varepsilon_n$ bounded from below, the asymptotics will also depend on $n$. Is it possible to see this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can include that term in $f$ and see what you get. Of course, it will show up in the error bound as well coming from the variation operator.